# How to set the default value of a Radio Button FormControl in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, I'm trying to set the default value of my radio button group like so:

TS:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.conditionsForm = this.fb.group({
        reportInjury: new FormControl('Yes', Validators.required),         
});
```

HTML:

```
<radio-button-wrapper formControlName="reportInjury" name="reportInjury">
    <radio heading="Yes" value="Yes" cid="reportInjuryYes"
            name="reportInjuryYes">
    </radio>

    <radio heading="No" value="No" cid="reportInjuryNo" name="reportInjuryNo">
    </radio>
</radio-button-wrapper>
```

When the page loads, the **Yes** radio button is selected by default, but if I send the form to a Node.js server *without touching* the radio button & print the radio button contents out to the console, ***undefined*** is displayed.

But, if I select the **No** radio button, then re-select the **Yes** radio button, then Yes will be printed on the console.

Here is how I'm displaying the value in app.js:

```
${content['formBody']['damageDetailsTwo']['damageReported'].value}
```

What changes do I need to make to ensure that if the user just clicks Send, that the default value ('Yes' in this case) is passed to the server? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using a third party library or your own custom radio component ?

Comment: did you try code in the demo below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set default value in

```
registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    reportInjury: ['yes', [Validators.required]]
  })
```

In HTML

```
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input id="yes" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="yes" name="reportInjury" formControlName="reportInjury">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="no" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="no" name="reportInjury" formControlName="reportInjury">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="no">No</label>
    </div>
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-default